# CHKJ2800E: <local> interface com.sbc.ept.imagine.service.adsl.ejb.AdslLocal, or one of its supertypes, cannot be reflected. Check the classpath

Tags: java, svn, ejb, rad, ejb-jar.xml

Currently I'm working for JAVA application. I just checked out project from SVN in RAD_9.1.1. When I added relevant jars to my project, I got stuck up with below class path error.

Do anyone has a solution for this problem?

Nearly 300+ errors has been thrown, I couldn't resolve the issue.

> CHKJ2800E:  interface
>   com.sbc.ept.imagine.service.adsl.ejb.AdslLocal, or one of its
>   supertypes, cannot be reflected. Check the
>   classpath.    ejb-jar.xml /ImagineService/ejbModule/META-INF

Comment: What are you using to build your application?  That sounds like a missing dependency.  Could you also tell us the class hierarchy of AdslLocal (I assume that's one of your own classes?)

Answer (score 2):

In order to resolve it:

1. Verify that the Java Build Path is set up correctly.

   In each project right-click -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export. Move ‘JRE System Library (jdk)’ to the top and have it check marked.
2. Right click the EJB project and click Validate. All the errors will disappear.

Refer to the following link as well:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/320119/EJB-JEE/java/error-deploying-ejb-CHKJ